# How to click on a anchor Tag using selenium webDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait

I am not able to click on the button having Some visibility issues. I need to hover around this first to get the link then i need to click on the same.

```
<a tabindex="0" 
   class="cardPreviewLink expand-icon" 
   aria-label="card opens in new tab" 
   target="_blank" 
   id="card-preview-link-19479" 
   href="/card/19479?$filters@$pattern=10532372&amp;type===&amp;dimension=chargeback_id"> 
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root" tabindex="-1" type="button">
    <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
      <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root open-icon" 
           focusable="false" 
           viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
           aria-hidden="true" 
           role="presentation">
        <path d="M19 19H5V5h7V3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-7h-2v7zM14 3v2h3.59l-9.83 9.83 1.41 1.41L19 6.41V10h2V3h-7z"/>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </button>
</a>
```

Code trials:

```
WebDriverWait wait4 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("cardPreviewLink expand-icon")));
driver.findElement(By.className("cardPreviewLink expand-icon")).click();
```

Error:

```
Timeout Exception because of No such Element Exception
```

Comment: Add some more information like, piece of code you used, type of exception etc.,

Comment: @Shubham Mishra make sure to mark the question that solves your issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to click with `webdriver wait` for `element to receive click`.

```
By buttonBy = By.cssSelector("a.cardPreviewLink.expand-icon > button"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buttonBy);
```

If above approach will not work you can try with `click using JS`. Here I am just waiting for `visibility of element` as If element can receive click then First approach should work.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(buttonBy);

WebElement button=driver.findElement(buttonBy);

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

Comment: It is throwing error at wait.until line. So how would it click using js ?

Comment: If you will remove wait  it should click as JS not depend on element’s state

Answer (score 2):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.cardPreviewLink.expand-icon > button.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root > span.MuiIconButton-label"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='cardPreviewLink expand-icon']/button[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root']/span[@class='MuiIconButton-label']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

By.className() won't work with names having spaces - **cardPreviewLink expand-icon**. Instead try to use cssSelector or xpath.

**Xpath Example:**

```
WebDriverWait wait4 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement element = wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'cardPreviewLink'][contains(@class,'expand-icon']")));
element.click();
```

'visibilityOfElementLocated' should work. If it didn't, as mentioned by Debanjan, try with 'elementToBeClickable'.
Also, wait.until will itself return WebElement object. You can use the same to click on it.